# Neo4j - Using Cypher to return a list of existing paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Imagine that I have the following graph:

[image: graph]

Ignore the relationships 3->2 and 4->3 of the graph to keep it a tree like structure.

**note:** in my case this type of relationships (4->3, 3->4) won't exist.

**Is it possible to use Cypher to return a "list" of all the existing paths in the graph?**

Example for the graph above:

Result: **1-2, 1-3, 1-3-4**

Preferably it should be **depth-first**.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the main use case of Cypher, so it will not perform very well, but it is possible.

Example dataset:

```
CREATE
  (n1:Node {name: 'n1'}),
  (n2:Node {name: 'n2'}),
  (n3:Node {name: 'n3'}),
  (n4:Node {name: 'n4'}),
  (n1)-[:REL]->(n2),
  (n1)-[:REL]->(n3),
  (n3)-[:REL]->(n4)
```

The query, using a [path variable](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/cypher/#_assigning_to_path_variables):

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*]->(b) RETURN p
```

The results:

```
╒════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│p                                           │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│[{name: n1}, {}, {name: n2}]                │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{name: n1}, {}, {name: n3}]                │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{name: n3}, {}, {name: n4}]                │
├────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│[{name: n1}, {}, {name: n3}, {}, {name: n4}]│
└────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

As Cypher is a declarative language, there are no options to enforce a breadth-/depth-first traversal. However, for that purpose Neo4j provides a [traversal framework](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorial-traversal) that you might find useful.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. If you don't mind me asking (I noticed you are a PhD student on graph processing), would I be able to show which graphs have some pattern? I mean, imagine I have other graphs similar to the one I showed, with some minor differences, and I want to find every graph (assuming they all have a root node like 1, with some name) that has the given pattern. E.g. If my database only had the above graph, and I would search for all the graphs that had the pattern 3->4, the return would be 1. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but you can easily search for concrete patterns, e.g. `MATCH ({name: 'n3'})-[]->({name: 'n4'}) RETURN *` and check if there are any results.